# installation and Internet module errors

Tags: installation, package

I hope this is the right place, I have recently installed **R** on an XP sp3 machine and it seems that anything that has to do with packages does not work for me. I'm getting an error massage whenever I'm trying to do something that has to do with Internet servers, this more or less the massage:

> starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In startDynamicHelp(TRUE) :
>     unable to load shared object 'D:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/modules/i386/internet.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

this does not allow me to install any packages and use R effectively
so if anyone has an idea how to resolve this or where is the right place to address this to, 
sharing this knowledge with me will be thanked and appreciated
:-)

Saar

Comment: I think this is a question for https://superuser.com/

Comment: Hi StuiterSlurf. In What subject do you think I should post it there?